# Java Pattern not matching RegEx

Tags: java, regex

Here is my issue. I have this:

```
String data = "java.awt.Color[r=168,g=228,b=160]" //example this changes.
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
if(m.matches()){
    ....
}
```

However, it is not matching. Why is that? I am trying to retrieve the numbers inside brackets.

What should I try?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Matcher.matches()` matches the complete string. You can use `Matcher.find` to match the individual integers:

```
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[`Matcher.matches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) tells you if your regex matches the *entire* string.  Your string isn't all digits.  It contains letters, dots, equal signs, and square brackets.  So you matcher doesn't match.

You want [`Matcher.find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29).  That searches for partial matches.  [`Matcher.group`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29) then allows you to retrieve the matched portion of the input string.

Answer (score 4):

The `matches` method will attempt to match the regex against *the entire input*.

Use a combination of the the [`find`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) and [`group`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28%29) methods method to find and use matches *within* the input:

```
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that the [`Matcher.matches()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) attempts to match against the *entire string*.

You want to use [`Matcher.find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Because your regex doesn't match the string, there are other characters before (and after) the \d matches after all.

Answer (score 1):

`matches()` method attempts to match the whole string, but you need just digit occurrences in it.
You need to use `find()` method and you might need to use `while` operator instead of `if` because it shifts `matcher` to next match occurrence.